# Filtering search using multiple dropdowns in MVC gives null Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently building an MVC application and I am trying to display a list of cars based on the selected dropdown. I dont want the user to have to select multiple dropdown to search, I want the code to be able to search by any combination of the dropdowns. I started wrinting the code with If else statements but I didnt think this was the best practice so I did some research and found a different way to filter my results. The issue that I am having is that the I am getting a null value in a Model.

This is my model

```
    public partial class Car 
{

    private Ignition_Hub_DBEntities Context;

    public IQueryable<Car> GetProducts(Car searchModel)
    {
        var result = Context.Cars.AsQueryable();
        if (searchModel != null)
        {
            if (searchModel.CarLotID.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.CarLotID == searchModel.CarLotID);
            if (searchModel.Available.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.Available == searchModel.Available);
            if (searchModel.ModelID.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.ModelID == searchModel.ModelID);
             if (searchModel.Model.MakeID.HasValue)
                return result;
            result = result.Where(x => x.Model.MakeID == searchModel.Model.MakeID);
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
        public Car()
    {
        Context = new Ignition_Hub_DBEntities();

    }
    public int? CarID { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool? Available { get; set; }
    public string VinNumber { get; set; }
    public int? CarLotID { get; set; }
    public int? ModelID { get; set; }

    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
    public virtual CarLot CarLot { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
        public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(Car searchModel)
    {

        var business = new Car();
        var model = business.GetProducts(searchModel);
        return PartialView("_Index", model);
}
```

Right now I get an error on `if (searchModel.Model.MakeID.HasValue)`
the error is `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` 
Thanks in advance for the help! If there is a better way to achieve this, please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the `Model` property of the search model is not null and has been passed to the action, then when searching you need to make sure `Model` property of the element in linq query is not null, then compare `MakeID` property of the search model with `MakeID` property of the element in linq query. For example if you are going to search based on `MakeID` of the `Model`, if it's been specified, then you need to change the code to the following:

```
if (searchModel.Model !=null && searchModel.Model.MakeID.HasValue)
    result = result.Where(x => x.Model !=null && 
        x.Model.MakeID == searchModel.Model.MakeID);
```

However if you are following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33154580/3110834), in general it's better to follow these advises:

- Do not use your Entity model as your POCO search model.
- Do not put business logic in your POCO class.
- If you are going to search based on MakeID, include it directly in the POCO search model.

**Example**

I'll extend the example from linked post, so the `Product` have a `Category` property as well and we are interested to search based on `CategoryName` as well as some other properties:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

You can create a `ProductSearchModel` class and put some fields you want to search based on them:

```
public class ProductSearchModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? PriceFrom { get; set; }
    public int? PriceTo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can put your search logic in `ProductBusinessLogic` class this way:

```
public class ProductBusinessLogic
{
    private YourDbContext Context;
    public ProductBusinessLogic()
    {
        Context = new YourDbContext();
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts(ProductSearchModel searchModel)
    {
        var result = Context.Products.AsQueryable();
        if (searchModel != null)
        {
            if (searchModel.Id.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.Id == searchModel.Id);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Name))
                result = result.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchModel.Name));
            if (searchModel.PriceFrom.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.Price >= searchModel.PriceFrom);
            if (searchModel.PriceTo.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.Price <= searchModel.PriceTo);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.CategoryName))
                result = result.Where(x => x.Category !=null && 
                    x.Category.Name.Contains(searchModel.Name));
        }
        return result;     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Your initial if statement in this answer fixed my issue. I will take your advise in using the POCOs  for better practice. However, I had a checkbox in my table that was checked if car is available and unchecked if car was unavailable. After adding this code, the checkbox turned into a select dropdown. Any reason for that?

Comment: No problem :) *After adding this code, the checkbox turned into a select dropdown* → no idea at the moment :\